# Too many open files when using jetty 9 on linux (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, jetty

I have a jetty 9.1.3 server running a grails application. When testing on os x everything is fine but on ubuntu I have noticed that it is opening a massive amount of files

If i run

```
lsof | awk '{ print $2; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

across the two platforms i see:

OS X:

**423** 1561

Ubuntu

**27393** 15238

I then ran a full lsof to see which files were used and i see repeated entries like:

java      15238 16672      jetty  mem       REG              202,1    575389    1239666 /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-root.war-_-any-6199673264702494065.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar

java      15238 16672      jetty  159r      REG              202,1    575389    1239666 /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-root.war-_-any-6199673264702494065.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar

This pattern is repeated over and over again in the lsof output and it happens for each jar on the classpath:

```
grep commons-collections lsof.log | wc -l
```

**138**

Can anyone explain what may be happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: Ever find the cause? I have a similar problem but the `lsof` output shows repeated open js files, from the exploded war in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 8):

I am experiencing the same problem.
I deployed my grails app on Jetty 7, Jetty 8, Jetty 9.0.2 and Jetty 9.1.5 (always on Ubuntu).
Everything works fine on all jetty versions, except for the last one, Jetty 9.1.5.
Jetty 9.1.5 on Windows 7 does run ok too.
So it seems there is a problem with Jetty 9.1.x on Ubuntu.

I fixed the problem editing the /etc/security/limits.conf file.
First run the following command:

```
ulimit -n
```

This will tell you the maximum file open limit (it was 1024 in my case).
As root, edit the /etc/security/limits.conf file and add these two lines:

```
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
```

For the changes to take effect, you should close the terminal session and open a new one.
You can run the `ulimit -n` command again to make sure of the changes.
Now start Jetty again and check if it runs ok.
This did it for me.